# How to delete 50% of rows that share a certain column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

```
df.groupby(['target']).count()
```

| Target | data |
| --- | --- |
| Negative | 103210 |
| Positive | 211082 |

Right now, my positive data is too large. I want to delete 50% of rows whose value in the `Target` column is `Positive`. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? do you want to remove 50% of the rows randomly?

Comment: Hi Derek, I only want to keep 100,000 positive data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep half of the `Positive` rows, [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) 50% of the `Positive` rows using `frac=0.5` and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) those indexes:

```
indexes = df[df.target == 'Positive'].sample(frac=0.5).index
df = df.drop(indexes)
```

To keep exactly 100K `Positive` rows, [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) 100K `Positive` rows using `n=100_000` and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them with the `Negative` rows:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df[df.target == 'Negative'],
    df[df.target == 'Positive'].sample(n=100_000)
])
```